# Rails config variables aren't found during initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, initialization, environment-variables

I have a file **config/initializers/secrets.rb** containing the following:

```
Rails.configuration.smtp_domain = "derp.com"
Rails.configuration.smtp_password = "derpderp"
Rails.configuration.smtp_user = "derp@derp.com"
Rails.configuration.smtp_address = "derp.derp.com"
```

In my **config/environments/development.rb** I have the following:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => Rails.configuration.smtp_address,
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => Rails.configuration.smtp_domain,
    :user_name            => Rails.configuration.smtp_user,                           
    :password             => Rails.configuration.smtp_password,
    :authentication       => 'login',                                                 
    :enable_starttls_auto => true                                                     
}
```

Now when I `bundle exec rails c` I get this error:

```
`method_missing': undefined method `smtp_address' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f8c4505b238> (NoMethodError)
```

However If I comment the smtp config out, then in the console I can do this:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.1)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.configuration.smtp_address
=> "derp.derp.com"
```

I can't comment this out in production, though! Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is that file path really config/initializers.secret.rb and not `config/initializers/secret.rb` ?

Comment: Oops! That was a typo the file is in the right place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. throwing some things out here, maybe that file is in the initializers directory correct?
2. Can you change your `Rails.configuration....` stuff and change it to constants instead. e.g., `SMTP_DOMAIN = 'derp.com'` etc.

Just wondering if that works first, then you can see wtf is going on with `Rails.configuration....` stuff. If this was TDD we'd say, let's get it green.  I've not seen Rails.configuration used like that personally, but who knows, maybe it's a thing.

Comment: I love your TDD analogy! Unfortunately, this gave me `uninitialized constant SMTP_ADDRESS (NameError)` This `Rails.configuration` style works for me loading env variables to my `schedule.rb` file with the whenever gem. There is something different in these environment files that is not happy with this approach, though.

Comment: Ok, now try `::SMTP_DOMAIN` (or whatever you called it) and see if that works. just to humour me.

Comment: I actually get the exact same error from my previous comment. The error message doesn't display the double-colon but I declared it that way in the development.rb file as you suggested. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I agree with pjammer that you should define your constants like he said (I had never seen `Rails.configuration` before). Anyway, I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem but be aware that Rails loads files in **alphabetical order**. So the file that defines those constants should have a name that comes before the files that use those constants. Also, and this is kinda silly but you never know, don't forget to restart your app every time you change your initializer files.

Answer (score 0):

Never saw this coming but if I add `require_relative 'initializers/secrets'` to the top of my `environment.rb` it works as I'd expect.

This is baffling to me since this *is* in an initializer which as I understand should already be loaded.

If anyone can explain why I'll happly accept your answer over my own. Thanks.